# regex to match words but not if a certain phrase

Tags: python, regex, conditional-statements

In python, I want to match substring containing two terms with up to a certain number of words in between **but not when it is equal to a certain substring.**

I have [this regular expression (regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/BlRMz8/1) that does the first part of the job, **matching two terms with up to a certain number of words in between.**

But I want to add a **part or condition with AND operator** to **exclude a specific sentence like "my very funny words"**

```
 my(?:\s+\w+){0,2}\s+words
```

Expected results for this input:

```
I'm searching for my whatever funny words inside this text
```

should match with **my whatever funny words**

while for this input:

```
I'm searching for my very funny words inside this text
```

**there should be no match**

Thank you all for helping out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use the following regex pattern:

```
my(?! very funny)(?:\s+\w+){0,2}\s+words
```

This inserts a negative lookahead `(?! very funny)` into your existing pattern to exclude the matches you don't want.  Here is a working [demo](https://regex101.com/r/6xSzNx/1).